# React doesn't trigger onClick if a setState happened before

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with controlled input elements. The inputs might have validations, and they are happening `onBlur` and if the user makes `onClick` on the submit button. If the validation state changes after checking (removing or adding errors), it will be stored in the React state, with a trigger of `setState`. If the validation state not changing (not adding errors, or not removing), the submit happens immediately. If there was an error, but the validation became successful on clicking, the `onBlur` triggers, and causes state changes, and the `onClick` doesn't even gets triggered, so the submit happens only by two clicks.

```js
    

    completeProcess = (val, process, maxLen) => process(val).substr(0, maxLen)
    //called inside render
    renderInputs = () => this.props.inputs.map(input => {
        const {
            id,
            validation,
            required = true,
            label,
            initValue = "",
            className = "",
            placeholder = "",
            type = "text",
            tag = "input",
            options = [],
            process = v => v,
            minLen = 0,
            maxLen = 20000
        } = input;

        const value = this.state[id] ? this.state[id].value : initValue;
        const error = this.state[id] ? this.state[id].error : null;

        const onBlur = () => {
            console.log("blur")
            this.setState({ [id]: {
                ...this.state[id],
                error: validate({value, validation, required, minLen})
            }});
        };
        const onChange = ({ target: { value: newValue }}) => this.setState(
            { [id]: {
                ...this.state[id],
                value: process(newValue)
            }}
        );
        return (
            <Input
                className={className}
                label={label}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                value={value}
                onBlur={onBlur}
                onChange={onChange}
                type={type}
                tag={tag}
                options={options}
                key={id}
                id={id}
                error={error}
            />
        );
    })
    
    //called on submit button click
        handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log("submit")
        const inputProps = this.state;
        const errors = {};
        const processedValues = {};

        this.props.inputs.map(
            ({
                id,
                required = true,
                validation,
                process = v => v,
                minLen = 0,
                maxLen = 20000
            }) => {
                    const { value } = inputProps[id];
                    errors[id] = validate(
                        {value, validation, required, minLen}
                    );
                    processedValues[id] = this.completeProcess(
                        value, process, maxLen
                    );
            }
        );

        const errorFree = Object.values(errors).every(e => !e);

        if (errorFree) {
            this.props.onSubmit(processedValues);
        } else {
            const newState = {};

            Object.keys(inputProps).forEach(id => {
                const { value } = inputProps[id];
                const error = errors[id];
                newState[id] = { value, error };
            });

            this.setState(newState);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your `validate` function do, what does it return? Can you include that code? Also, what about `this.completeProcess`?

Comment: Also, why, in `handleSubmit` do you use `map` on `this.inputs`? `forEach` seems more appropriate since you aren't intending to return a new array.

Comment: Sorry, it's just a bit longer code. I attached what completeProcess does, it does the same at onChange, I just edited it for a more readable code. Validate just returns a a string (error) or null if it's error free

Comment: Okay. that helps understand more what is going on. The question is when you have two events that are firing near the same time, which fires first? If you have focus on an input, then click on submit, the input's `onBlur` will fire, as should the buttons `onClick`, but which fires first and could they collide with one another? That seems to be the question, right?

Comment: It may be that react is batching your set states, but because it's using old state in the last setting it ends up only changing once. I can't tell as your snippet isn't running for me.

Comment: onBlur fires first. If the field is error-free, and it passes through the validation when you click on the button (and outside the input), because there's no setState, onBlur and both onClick fires. If the situation is that the field failed on validation, you edit it that way that it passes and click on the button, onBlur validates, and deletes the error from the state. It looks like the setState stops the next event, onClick from firing.